# In React how to PROPERLY pass input value from child to parent

Tags: reactjs, react-props

I have a simple code in [sandbox][1] and below

[1]: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-72dprn to pass input form value to child to parent but something is wrong and the value didn't get passed.

This is the app.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import Hello from './Hello';
import './style.css';
import Form from './form'

class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      value: ""
    };
  }

  handleSubmit = e=>{
    this.setState({
      value=e.target.value
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

And the Form.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
class form extends Component {   
    render() { 
        return (
          <form className="replyForm" onSubmit={this.props.onSubmit}>
           <input /> 
           <button type="submit" className='btn btn-success'>Submit</button>
          </form>);   } }   
export default form;
```

Any help greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are so many mistakes in your code. You should read the [react docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#props-in-jsx) properly

First of all you are setting your state incorrectly -

```
  handleSubmit = e=>{
    this.setState({
      value: e.target.value   //this is an object don't assign a value//
    })
  }
```

Second - In your **form.js** your component starts with a lowercase. React components start with an uppercase -

```
class Form extends Component {   
    render() { 
        return (
          <form className="replyForm" onSubmit={this.props.onSubmit}>
           <input /> 
           <button type="submit" className='btn btn-success'>Submit</button>
          </form>);   } }   
export default Form;
```

Now coming to your original question, To pass the value of input to child you need to pass it as props and use it in child as props -

```
<Form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} inputValue={this.state.value} />
```

In your child component access that value as `this.props.value`.

Comment: (Sorry for the typos. Those were due to issue with saving and it turned out to be an earlier unsaved version.) I don't get why one needs a inputValue in the Form component, but thanks to your answer somehow got it working, without inputValue props.

Comment: @burriko well , i am glad it worked somehow. You don't need the inputValue in form component if you are not using that value directly there. If this somehow helped you then please accept it as an answer. :)